# New User in AD with multiple OUs

Tags: powershell, automation, scripting, active-directory

My first post here.

So here is how it goes,

The end goal is to place the New User in the specific OU, under its distinguished name as path. I can resolve this with one subsequent OU selections, but once there are multiple, I would like to avoid the subsequent scripting, because the number of subsequent OUs can change.

Does anyone have an idea how to create a loop or any other solution that will continue to ask me through each layer of OU's until desired OU is chosen.

For example, User will be employed as Safety in US, under state IL, in city Chicago
My OU configuration would be as follows:
US
IL
Chicago
Safety
Users

I would like the script to loop through each layer until I've chosen Users, or a parameter to my liking. Note that each of subsequent OU's would have multiple choices, which I would like to sort and choose within a Grid. I already know this part, but what's tricky for me is creating that loop.

Not very familiar with While Do Until on powershell.

I will do my research but would appreciate any suggestions. It doesn't have to be a loop, but I'm looking for a solution with $ instead of a definite parameter.

Cheers,

```
if ($Location -eq $null )
{
[System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show("'You didn't enter the required parameter, script ending'","System Notification","Ok")
 exit
}
if ($Location -ne $null )               
{
while ($Location -ne $null) {
  $DomainOU1=Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter "Name -like '$Location'" -SearchBase $DistinguishedGroupName -SearchScope OneLevel | select Name -ExpandProperty Name
  }
do {
  $Location1=@($DomainOU1) | sort
  $Location1=$Location1 | Out-GridView -Title "Choose Employee Location of Deployment"
  $Location1=$Location
}
Until ($Location -eq "Users")
}
Write-output "You chose $Location"
```

Comment: To be clear: an AD user can belong to many groups, but like any object must belong to **exactly one** OU. It's not totally clear, but the question seems to indicate you may actually want multiple OUs for, say, both "Safety" and "Chicago, IL, USA"

Answer (score 0):

Not a full answer, but this looks problematic:

```
while ($Location -ne $null) {
  $DomainOU1=Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter "Name -like '$Location'" -SearchBase $DistinguishedGroupName -SearchScope OneLevel | select Name -ExpandProperty Name
  }
```

It loops based on the `$location` variable, but nothing in the loop will ever change the `$location` variable, so it will loop forever.

Comment: Appreciate your response.

It was my understanding that this might:
$Location1=$Location

Comment: It will not, for two reasons: `1)` It assigns to `$Location1`, not `$Location`, which still remains unchanged. `2)` That code is _after_ this loop, so that assignment won't ever run until this loop finishes, which will never happen. You may need to get a more fundamental understanding a basic assignment and control flow :(

Comment: You are absolutely right Sir. I haven't improved my understanding, and that's a good Location to start. :)

Answer (score 0):

So what I've decided to do in this case, is to add Users/Computers OU to all Destination OU's, and filter the $ by Users.

```
$EmployeeOU=Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter "Name -like 'Users'" -SearchBase (Get-ADDomain).DistinguishedName | select Name,DistinguishedName

$Location=@($EmployeeOU) | sort
$Location=$Location | Out-GridView -Title "Choose Employee Location of Employment" -PassThru
```

This allows me to put the user in desired location by showing me the DistinguishedName OU details.